# jQuery validate stopping the form post action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which will upload a CSV file to a server. I am trying to validate the file type before sending it to the server. I am using `jquery.validate.js` and `addition-function.js` to do this. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/d3XpL/) i created.

Although it is validating but i am getting an issue while uploading.
To replicate the issue, first choose any random file other then .csv and then if you press the upload button then it warns you with

> Please enter a value with a valid extension.

Now if you choose the correct file type which is .csv then the error label is removed but the form doesn't post. The form will post if i press on upload twice.

Please advice on this.

Comment: Firstly, when you try to post a jsFiddle link without code, you get a SO warning message.   This is because your question should not depend solely on a link in order to remain useful.  Secondly, there is no reason for your `submitHandler` when it only contains a `submit()` as this is already the default.  I see nothing in your jsFiddle that should require you to click twice.

Comment: @Sparky I have added "submitHandler" just to alert when the POST action is happening. Were you not able to replicate the issue by following the steps i mentioned? The main issue is that i need to press the upload button twice to POST.

Comment: I understand your problem description clearly.  However, your code cannot explain the issue described.  I cannot test anything yet since I'm mobile, so I'll try it later.